# Does DXA 1.4 work with the CIS 8.1.0 services?

Tags: dxa, web8

DXA 1.4 comes with the SDL Web 8.1.1 CIL (Content Interaction Library). Is the 8.1.1 version of CIL compatible with the 8.1.0 CIS (Content Interation Serivces)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's one of the reasons why the release dates were coordinated.

Comment: Are all CIS en CIL micro versions interchangable by design? So can I use a 8.1.0 CIL with a 8.1.1 Content service too? And in the future with 8.1.2 CIS?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea; we won't be changing the contract in a non-compatible manner (for sure not in Patch Releases). The general idea behind Service Oriented Architecture is that client and server are loosely coupled (and versioned).

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate a bit on Nuno's Answer: the release dates were coordinated to ensure that DXA 1.4 could build upon CIL 8.1.1.  We have also tested it against CIS 8.1.0, though.

Note, however, that there were several defects in SDL Web 8.1.0 which required hotfixes to make DXA 1.3+ work properly (in particular with XPM, see DXA 1.3 docs). These hotfixes have been included in 8.1.1, so I would strongly recommend to upgrade to 8.1.1.